# What's the difference between @Constraints.Required and @Formats.NonEmpty?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

When creating a Model in Play! 2.x, you can use `@Constraints.Required` and `@Formats.NonEmpty`. As I understand them, they are the same, but the [ZenTasks sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/models/User.java) uses them both in the same field, so I'm probably wrong. But why?

```
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String email;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constraints and Formats have complete different targets. Once is for formatting and the other for vaildation, so

- `@Constraints.Required` is a validation, which ensures that the value not null.
- `@Formats.NonEmpty` is a formatter, which trims the input and if the string then has a length of 0 (`text.trim().isEmpty()`) it returns null. So the value is set to null. After that the Required-annotation can do the job.

So it's often useful to use both, but not in every situation.

Answer (score 3):

- `@Constraints.Required` checks if property was sent at all so you can just send empty `space` char and it will be valid
- `@Formats.NonEmpty` additionally checks if trimmed value is not empty

Comment: So would `@Formats.NonEmpty` include `@Constraints.Required`? Why use both then?

Comment: Not quite sure about that, but probably `@Constraints.Required` checks if variable is available and `@Formats` checks only the value, so most probably if you'll try validate only with `@Formats` you'll gain Null exception when no variable is sent. (note: I didn't check this assumption, just using both by default)

Answer (score 1):

`@Formats.NonEmpty` transforms result first `@Constraints.Required` checks transformed one.

For e.g:
the string is `"   "` will pass `@Constraints.Required`, so, adding `@Formats.NonEmpty` will firstly trim `"   "` to `null` and `@Contraints.Required` could fires an error.